# How to escape special charcters?

Tags: special-characters, htmlpurifier

I am using a [html purifier](https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier) package for purifying my rich text from any xss before storing in database.

But my rich text allows for Wiris symbols which uses special character as `&#8594;` or `&#160;`.

Problem is the package does not allow me to escape these characters. It removes them completely.
What should I do to escape them ??

Example of the string before purifying

```html
<p><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>&#160;</mo><mo>+</mo><mo>&#160;</mo><mmultiscripts><mi>y</mi><mprescripts/><none/><mn>2</mn></mmultiscripts><mo>&#160;</mo><mover><mo>&#8594;</mo><mo>=</mo></mover><mo>&#160;</mo><msup><mi>z</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mo>&#160;</mo></math></p>
```

After purifying

```html
<p><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><msup><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mo> </mo><mo>+</mo><mo> </mo><mmultiscripts><mi>y</mi><mprescripts></mprescripts><none><mn>2</mn></mmultiscripts><mo> </mo><mover><mo>→</mo><mo>=</mo></mover><mo> </mo><msup><mi>z</mi><mn>2</mn></msup><mo> </mo></math></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by setting key [`Core.EscapeNonASCIICharacters`](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#Core.EscapeNonASCIICharacters) to true

under my `default` key in my `purifier.php` file and the problem has gone.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that these entities are failing the regexen that HTML Purifier is using to check for valid entities in `HTMLPurifier_EntityParser`, [here](https://repo.or.cz/htmlpurifier.git/blob/HEAD:/library/HTMLPurifier/EntityParser.php#l45):

```php
         $this->_textEntitiesRegex =
             '/&(?:'.
             // hex
             '[#]x([a-fA-F0-9]+);?|'.
             // dec
             '[#]0*(\d+);?|'.
             // string (mandatory semicolon)
             // NB: order matters: match semicolon preferentially
             '([A-Za-z_:][A-Za-z0-9.\-_:]*);|'.
             // string (optional semicolon)
             "($semi_optional)".
             ')/';
 
         $this->_attrEntitiesRegex =
             '/&(?:'.
             // hex
             '[#]x([a-fA-F0-9]+);?|'.
             // dec
             '[#]0*(\d+);?|'.
             // string (mandatory semicolon)
             // NB: order matters: match semicolon preferentially
             '([A-Za-z_:][A-Za-z0-9.\-_:]*);|'.
             // string (optional semicolon)
             // don't match if trailing is equals or alphanumeric (URL
             // like)
             "($semi_optional)(?![=;A-Za-z0-9])".
             ')/';
```

Notice how it expects numeric entities to start with `0` currently. (Perfectly sane since it's designed to handle pure HTML, without add-ons, and to make that safe; but in your use-case, you want more entity flexibility.)

You could extend that class and overwrite the constructor (where these regexen are being defined, by instead defining your own where you remove the `0*` from the `// dec` part of the regexen), instantiating that, try setting `$this->_entity_parser` on a Lexer created with `HTMLPurifier_Lexer::create($config)` to your instantiated EntityParser object (this is the part I am least sure about whether it would work; you might have to create a Lexer patch with `extends` as well), then supply the altered Lexer to the config using [`Core.LexerImpl`](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#Core.LexerImpl).

I have no working proof-of-concept of these steps for you right now (especially in the context of Laravel), but you should be able to go through those motions in the `purifier.php` file, before the `return`.

Comment: Thanks much for your answer, I found a simpler solution by just setting Core.EscapeNonASCIICharacters to true in my configurations file.

Comment: But I encountered anther problem ^--^

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71898104/htmlpurifier-how-to-escape-self-closing-tags

If you are able to give my any help, I would be very thankful.